# Yii dealing with forms

Tags: php, yii

I have form where are 2 input fields and then i have dynamic `dataTables` in this form which contain `checkboxes` and 2 input fields in each table. I need to send form data including tables data with `POST`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well question is not clear because of uncertainty of your approach. I guess we can answer more precise but for reference you can have a look at 
[How to use a single form to collect data for two or more models?](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/) and also [multimodelform](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multimodelform/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to use [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.model) here too.